# NameError exception thrown within my script - unsure why

Tags: python, python-2.7

​I'm supposed to build a Python program that takes in a user input as a string. This program is required to add every string entered into a list until "John" is entered and then print out the list.

Essentially, this program stores all incorrectly entered strings in a list where “John” is the only correct string.

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dwayne/doen.py", line 7, in <module>
    if names_entered == "John":
NameError: name 'names_entered' is not defined`
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
name = "John"
while name != 'John':
names_entered = raw_input('Enter your name: ')


if names_entered == "John":
print []
```

Comment: It does not enter the `while` loop. `name` does equal to `'John'`

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is incorrect; the bodies of the while loop and the if must be indented.

After that, the compiler is quite correct: since the **if** is at the same level as the **while**, there's no guarantee that **names_entered** will have a value at that point.

Even if you fix that, you have other problems:

1. You force **name** to "John" before the loop, you'll never enter the loop.
2. When you do find "John" you print an empty list.
3. There is no code to append the other names to a list.

I hope this gets you moving; it still doesn't accumulate names in a list; that's for you.

```
name = ""
while name != 'John':
    names_entered = raw_input('Enter your name: ')

    if names_entered == "John":
        print []
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some help logic-wise.  You're setting the "name" variable to "John" before your WHILE loop, which is checking to see if the "name" variable is equal to "John".  What this means is that the WHILE condition is satisfied before you even get to accepting any kind of input.  That also means that anything that is declared WITHIN the while loop is never touched, so never actually declared.  So when you go to access "names_entered" in the IF statement below the WHILE loop, "names_entered" was never assigned any values (it wasn't declared), so you get an error.

My logical solution is this:

Set the "name" variable to an empty string before you get the to WHILE loop.  When you hit the loop, the condition won't be satisfied (an empty string does NOT equal "John"), so the contents of the loop will then be considered.

What you're trying to do with the input is build a list of names that you know will eventually end with the name "John".  So you need a list (a string array) to add all those names to BEFORE you even get to the WHILE loop.  Declare an empty string array (your "names_entered") up where you declare the "name" variable.   THEN, when you go to accept input from the user (into the "name" variable), you'll add each entry you get into the "names_entered" variable, which you'll eventually print out.

In your code, you are attempting to put the user input directly into your list.  Instead, assign the input to your "name", which will then (after you've added "name" to "names_entered") be tested by your WHILE loop to see if it equals "John".  When "name" equals "John", the WHILE condition will be satisfied, and the code below the WHILE loop will then be processed.

As for printing out the list, you will have to loop through the array of names you've collected and print each one out to the console.  Maybe a "for" loop?

Sorry for the lack of code, but hopefully the logic assistance will help.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @jaltman It just prints me the "John"
With the following code below:


name = ""
names_entered = ""
while name != 'John':
    name = raw_input('Enter your name: ')

    if names_entered == name:
        print names_entered

Comment: You're gonna have to step back from the actual code for a second.  Think about what you want to do.  You want to take in user input, each entry representing a single name.  You want to do this until you encounter the name "John".  Meanwhile, you're adding each entry to a list you're building to keep track of all the names that have been entered.  Once you encounter "John", there's no more looping, and you just print out the list you've built.   If you've dropped out of the loop, you already know you've got "John", so you can print out the list you've built.  No further testing is necessary.